# In-Place Quicksort in Python

Tags: python, sorting, quick-sort

Code is below. I'd like to know if this is a solid/efficient implementation of the in-place quicksort algorithm and if my Python style is good (I know there are no comments for now). Code is also on Github here if you'd like: https://github.com/michaelrbock/data-structs-and-algos/blob/master/Sorts/quicksort.py Thanks!

```
def quicksort(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst
    lst, store_index = partition(lst)
    return quicksort(lst[:store_index-1]) + [lst[store_index-1]] + quicksort(lst[store_index:])

def partition(lst):
    if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
        middle = (len(lst) / 2) - 1
    else:
        middle = len(lst) / 2

    pivot_choice = get_median( [lst[0], lst[middle], lst[len(lst)-1]] )

    if pivot_choice == lst[0]:
        PIVOT_INDEX = 0
    elif pivot_choice == lst[middle]:
        PIVOT_INDEX = middle
    elif pivot_choice == lst[len(lst)-1]:
        PIVOT_INDEX = len(lst) - 1

    pivot = lst[PIVOT_INDEX]
    lst[0], lst[PIVOT_INDEX] = lst[PIVOT_INDEX], lst[0]
    i = 1
    for j in range(1, len(lst)):
        if lst[j] < pivot:
            lst[j], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[j]
            i += 1
    lst[0], lst[i-1] = lst[i-1], lst[0]
    return lst, i

def get_median(nums):
    values = sorted(nums)
    if len(values) % 2 == 1:
        return values[(len(values)+1)/2-1]
    else:
        lower = values[len(values)/2-1]
        upper = values[len(values)/2]
    return (lower+upper)/2
```

Comment: Doesn't using `sorted` in a sorting function defeat the purpose of writing your own sorting function?

Comment: yes, yes it would. But in this case, `sorted()` in only used in the choice of pivot, which is really just some preprocessing outside of the quicksort. Though perhaps some more imaginative implementation would have been more in tune with the problem

Comment: The in-place sort doesn't work correctly.  The returned list is sorted, but the list that you call `quicksort` on isn't neccessarily.  `a = [2,99,1,0,3]; print quicksort(a), a` prints `[0, 1, 2, 3, 99] [0, 1, 2, 99, 3]`.

Comment: @flornquake, good point thanks. Any suggestions on how to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like the style (especially the nice clear function and variable names). As its quicksort most of the code is straightforward enough that comments would probably only add meaning when it comes to the swapping. You should probably try and use four spaces, rather than tabs, for indenting the code (it's just common practice). The only minor stylistic change I would personally make is to uncapitalise `PIVOT_INDEX`. I know technically it is constant (in that it doesn't change value after it's assigned), but I just prefer to have one clear assignment for any constant values. However, I'm sure other people would disagree.

As for efficiency, you're always going to be bounded by the algorithm itsef, but there are a couple changes you could make. You calculate `len(lst)` multiple times in partition. Rather than doing that, you could just assign it like `list_length = len(lst)` once at the start of the partition function. Not a big deal I know. The only other meaningful change I can think of is in your `get_median` function. As you know that it's always called with three values you could change it to:

```
def get_median(nums):
    values = sorted(nums)
    return values[1]
```

If you really want to be fancy you can replace the `get_median` and the whole if-then-else construct that determines the `PIVOT_INDEX` with something like:

```
PIVOT_INDEX = sorted(zip([lst[0], lst[middle], lst[list_length - 1]], [0, middle, list_length]))[1][1]
```

which will give you the index (0, `middle` or `list_length`) of the median value in the same way.

Comment: `len` [is an O(1) operation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for Python lists, i.e. you don't calculate the length, you just read it. So there's no significant improvement there.

Comment: True. I suppose I worded it badly. I just meant that assigning a value to a variable is easier for the reader/writer of the code than explicitly evaluating it each time (although I suppose with len() its not a big deal).

Answer (score 1):

Your style is good.

I had a little improvement for efficiency. Instead of using the condition `i % 2 == 0` for checking i as an even number you can instead use `i % 2` as a condition for checking i as an  odd number. It reduces the number of comparisons and doesn't effect the functionality at all. It might not have the best readability but it improves time-efficiency. A simple comment can offset the readability lost.

Also this seems like Python 2 so instead of using `range` which returns a list you should use `xrange` which returns a generator when you are looping. It costs a little time-performance but is usually compensated by the huge improvement in memory-performance.

Also in the `median` function you can probably eliminate the `lower` and `upper` variable by using something like

```
return (
    values[len(values)/2-1] +
    values[len(values)/2]
    )/2
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: `xrange` is not only more efficient than `range` memory-wise, it's also quite a bit faster when all you want to do is loop over a range of numbers.

As for the `lower` and `upper` variables, I think it is perfectly fine to assign them, even if you only use them once.  Giving the values a name makes it immediately obvious what the piece of code is doing  (imo it is even more readable than an explanatory comment would be).